# Derive monoid instance for custom `Maybe` data type

Tags: haskell

For learning purposes, i am trying to create an `Optional` data type that mimics `Maybe` in the typeclass instance of `Monoid` where

```
-- Data.Monoid> Prelude.mappend (Just [1,2]) (Just [3,4])
-- Just [1,2,3,4]
```

Instead, I am getting the behavior of the `First` instance of `Maybe` for `Monoid`.

```
-- Data.Monoid> (First (Just [1,2])) <> (First (Just [3,4]))
-- First {getFirst = Just [1,2]}
```

My data type and typeclass instance are:

```
data Optional a =
  Nada
  | Only a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

 instance Monoid a
  => Monoid (Optional a) where
mempty = Nada
mappend x mempty = x
mappend mempty (Only x) = Only x
mappend (Only x) (Only y) = Only (Prelude.mappend x y)
```

My questions are

- Why does it behave like this?
- How do I get `mappend` for `Optional` to behave like the instance for `Maybe` that concatenates lists rather than taking the first `Only` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it behave like this?

Because that is how [**`First`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:First) has been designed. The idea of `First` is to "wrap" a `Maybe a` value, and to implement the `Monoid` like:

```
instance Monoid (First a) where
    mempty = First Nothing
    mappend l@(First (Just _)) _ = l
    mappend _ x = x
```

It thus returns the first `First` constructor that wrapps a value `Just` data constructor. This can be useful when we use the `mconcat`:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> mconcat [First Nothing, First (Just 0), First Nothing, First (Just 118), First (Just 999)]
First {getFirst = Just 0}
```

We thus do not use the `Monoid (Maybe a)` implementation, the `First` decides how the `Monoid` looks like. A similar thing happens with [**`Sum`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:Sum) and [**`Product`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:Product)

> How do I get `mappend` for `Optional` to behave like the instance for `Maybe` that concatenates lists rather than taking the first `Only` value?

There is an *error* in your definition. You use `mempty` in the head of a function like:

```
mappend x mempty = x
```

is *just a variable named `mempty`*. So the first line will match *everything*. You should fix it, like you intend with:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Optional a) where
    mempty = Nada
    mappend x Nada = x
    mappend Nada x = x
    mappend (Only x) (Only y) = Only (Prelude.mappend x y)
```

Comment: D'oh. It makes perfect sense now. Checking `Main.mappend (Nada) (Only [3,4])
== Nada` would have made that clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: @neallred Turning on warnings warns about the issue: "This binding for ‘mempty’ shadows the existing binding". Keep warnings enabled to avoid this in the future.